# django form doesn't go inside post

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, request

I am just trying to be able to read the values entered by the user on the form in the server.
I have noticed that it never goes inside this part of the view function

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
```

Please let me know if I missed anything. I have included my code snippets for views, urls, form, html files:

```
urls.py=>
urlpatterns = [
    path('create',views.create),
    path('create/',views.create),
    path('download', views.download),
]

checklistform.py=>
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()

create.html=>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
 </form>
</body>
</html>

views.py =>
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, redirect
from .checklistform import ContactForm

def create(request):
    print("letssee")
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            print(name)

    form=ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
```

Output seen in pycharm => (as we can see it never goes inside the if)

```
[15/Aug/2020 23:47:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2038
letssee
GET
[15/Aug/2020 23:47:08] "GET /imschecklist/create HTTP/1.1" 200 364
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Did you *submit* the form? I don't see an `action=...` in the form?

Comment: I did submit the form. I have also tried with  the following on the html file  but that didn't make any difference: <form method="POST" action="/create">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<html lang="en>` change to `<html lang="en">`. You miss double quote.

Comment: I have tried that as well but I still have the same issue.

Comment: ```<html lang="en>``` change to ```<html lang="en">```. You remove  double quote.